# PHP weird problem with file_get_html

Tags: php, screen-scraping

Hi i am trying to use simple_html_dom for a text(website) clustering project but i have run into a weird problem. When i use echo inside the outer loop the url and the snippet are what you would expect but when i try to echo the array contents i have gathered outside the loop the urls are ok but the snippets are gone and the last snippet is in their place.

```
<?php
  // create HTML DOM
  include("simple_html_dom.php");
  $search_query = 'something';
  $j = 1;
  $k = 1;
  /*************************GOOGLE***************************/
  for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
      $url = sprintf('http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&start=%d', $search_query, 10 * $i);
      $html = file_get_html($url);
      foreach ($html->find('a[class=l]') as $element) {
          $urls[$j] = $element->href;
          echo $element->href . "\n\n\n\n\n";
          $j++;
      }
      foreach ($html->find('div[class=s]') as $element) {
          $snippets[$k] = $element->innertext;
          echo $element->innertext . "\n\n\n\n\n";
          $k++;
      }
  }
  $j = 1;
  foreach ($snippets as $elemement) {
      echo $urls[$j] . "\n" . $element . "\n\n\n\n";
      $j++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please post readable code the next time, you can use http://www.phpformatter.com/ for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you did not made a typo in your code?

```
foreach ($snippets as $elemement) {
      echo $urls[$j] . "\n" . $element . "\n\n\n\n";
      $j++;
  }
```

`element` and `elemement` are different; Your loop executes fine but your statement probably doesn't.

Comment: yep thanks. its so obvious to all of you yet i spent 30 mins looking at it, ....must sleep!

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo, `$elemenent` really should be `$element`.

```
foreach ($snippets as $element) {
    echo $urls[$j] . "\n" . $element . "\n\n\n\n";
    $j++;
}
```

This is one reason to get used to make readable code. It's not because others like it, but because it makes debugging much easier.

Comment: LOL thanks man! I dont usualy have problems reading my huge unreadable codes but i really need sleep right now.